# Reduce by key on device array

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, thrust

I am using reduce_by_key to find the number of elements in an array of type int2 which has same first values .

For example
Array: <1,2> <1,3> <1,4> <2,5> <2,7> 
so no. elements with 1 as first element are 3 and with 2 are 2.

**CODE:**

```
struct compare_int2 : public thrust::binary_function<int2, int2, bool> {
__host__ __device__ bool operator()(const int2 &a,const int2 &b) const{
return (a.x == b.x);}
};

compare_int2 cmp;
int main()
{
        int n,i;
        scanf("%d",&n);

        int2 *h_list = (int2 *) malloc(sizeof(int2)*n);
        int *h_ones = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

        int2 *d_list,*C;
        int  *d_ones,*D;
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_list,sizeof(int2)*n);
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_ones,sizeof(int)*n);
        cudaMalloc((void **)&C,sizeof(int2)*n);
        cudaMalloc((void **)&D,sizeof(int)*n);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                int2 p;
                printf("Value ? ");
                scanf("%d %d",&p.x,&p.y);
                h_list[i] = p;
                h_ones[i] = 1;
        }

        cudaMemcpy(d_list,h_list,sizeof(int2)*n,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(d_ones,h_ones,sizeof(int)*n,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        thrust::reduce_by_key(d_list, d_list+n, d_ones, C, D,cmp);
        return 0;
}
```

The above code is showing Segmentation Fault . I ran the above code using gdb and it reported the segfault at this location.

> thrust::system::detail::internal::scalar::reduce_by_key >
>   (keys_first=0x1304740000,keys_last=0x1304740010,values_first=0x1304740200,keys_output=0x1304740400, values_output=0x1304740600,binary_pred=...,binary_op=...)
>
> at /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/detail/internal/scalar/reduce_by_key.h:61 61
>   InputKeyType  temp_key   = *keys_first

**How to use reduce_by_key on device arrays ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thrust interprets ordinary pointers as pointing to data on the host:

```
    thrust::reduce_by_key(d_list, d_list+n, d_ones, C, D,cmp);
```

Therefore thrust will call the *host path* for the above algorithm, and it will seg fault when it attempts to dereference those pointers in host code.  This is covered in the [thrust getting started guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide):

> You may wonder what happens when a "raw" pointer is used as an argument to a Thrust function. Like the STL, Thrust permits this usage and it will dispatch the host path of the algorithm. If the pointer in question is in fact a pointer to device memory then you'll need to wrap it with  thrust::device_ptr  before calling the function.

Thrust has a variety of mechanisms (e.g. `device_ptr`, `device_vector`, and execution policy) to identify to the algorithm that the data is device-resident and the device path should be used.

The simplest modification for your existing code might be to use `device_ptr`:

```
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
...
thrust::device_ptr<int2> dlistptr(d_list);
thrust::device_ptr<int>  donesptr(d_ones);
thrust::device_ptr<int2> Cptr(C);
thrust::device_ptr<int>  Dptr(D);
thrust::reduce_by_key(dlistptr, dlistptr+n, donesptr, Cptr, Dptr,cmp);
```

The issue described above is similar to [another issue you asked about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706907/segmentation-error-when-using-thrustsort-in-cuda).