# Using Thrust Functions with raw pointers: Controlling the allocation of memory

Tags: memory-management, cuda, thrust

I have a question regarding the thrust library when using CUDA. 
I am using a thrust function, i.e. [exclusive_scan](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__prefixsums_ga7be5451c96d8f649c8c43208fcebb8c3.html), and I want to use raw pointers. I am using raw (device) pointers because I want to have full control of when the memory is allocated and deallocated.

After the function call, I will hand over the pointer to another data structure and then free the memory in either the destructor of this data structure, or in the next function call, when I recompute my (device) pointers. I came across for example [this problem here now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706907/segmentation-error-when-using-thrustsort-in-cuda), which recommends to wrap the data structure in a device_vector. But then I run into the problem that the memory is freed once my device_vector goes out of scope, which I do not want. Having the device pointer globally is also not an option, since I am hacking code, i.e. it is used as a buffer and I would have to rewrite a lot if I wanted to do something like that.

Does anyone have a good workaround regarding this? The only chance I do see right now is to rewrite the thrust-function on my own, only using raw device-pointers.

EDIT: I misread, I can wrap it in a device_ptr instead of a device_vector.
Asking further though, how could I solve this if there wasn't the option of using a device_ptr?

Comment: The question you linked to recommends wrapping in a **`device_ptr`**, not a **`device_vector`**.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I did oversee that detail, thank you.
That leaves me with the question still however how I could do my memory management if I would not have this option. Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: Use the dispatch policy version of the APIs, I would guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem using plain pointers in thrust methods.

For data on the device do:

```
....
struct DoSomething {
    __device__ int operator()(int item) { return 1; }
};

int* IntData;
cudaMalloc(&IntData, sizeof(int) * count);
auto dev_data = device_pointer_cast(IntData);
thrust::generate(dev_data, dev_data + count, DoSomething());
thrust::sort(dev_data, dev_data + count);
....
cudaFree(IntData);
```

For data on the host use plain `malloc/free` and `raw_pointer_cast` instead of `device_pointer_cast`.
See: [thrust: Memory management](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__memory__management__functions.html)

Comment: Technically that isn't using plain pointers. Plain pointer support would involve the dispatch policy versions of the thrust APIs